# What does "~[]" do?

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I saw the following line of code [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_external_strace/blob/master/tests-mx32/sigprocmask.c#L76) .

```
puts("sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, ~[], []) = 0");
```

I don't understand, what does empty array script(`[]`) do?

Also, What is the purpose of `~[]` in C?

Comment: It's in a string literal. It doesn't *do* anything in C.

Comment: @rsp, incorrect, not "It doesn't do anything", but "It doesn't do anything **in C**"

Comment: I think the question is not bad. Why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked program seems to be logging its actions in some invented semi-formalized language. This logging "language" is not C. The string literal in your question is just a line in that invented "language", which the program will send to standard output. Therefore the `~[]` bit has notrhing to do with C and has no special meaning in C context.

After each (supposedly succesful) `k_sigprocmask` call the progrtam logs that call by sending such strings to the output.

For example, when the program outputs `sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL) = <something>` it basically just tells the user "I just called `k_sigprocmask` function with first argument `SIG_SETMASK`, empty set of bits as the second argument and a null pointer as the third argument. And I received `<something>` as the error code."

`[]` stands for all-bits-zero bit mask (empty set). `[HUP INT QUIT]` stands for a mask with only `HUP`, `INT` and `QUIT` bits set to 1. `~[HUP]` stands for a mask with all bits set to 1 except `HUP` bit.

`~[]` stands for a strange argument value `new_set - 1`, which does not immediately make sense to me (since `new_set` is a pointer). I presume it somehow results in a set with all elements included (all bits set to 1).

Answer (score 3):

It does **nothing**.

```
puts("sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, ~[], []) = 0");
     ^                                     ^
```

It's a string literal. This line is probably used to generate a program in another language, which at least isn't C.

Answer (score 1):

The [reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) say's :

> On the other hand, **bit-sets** are **also shown using square brackets** but
>   set elements are separated only by a space. Here is the shell
>   preparing to execute an external command:
>
> ```
> sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TTOU], []) = 0
> ```
>
> Here **the second argument is a bit-set of two signals, SIGCHLD and
>   SIGTTOU. In some cases the bit-set is so full that printing out the
>   unset elements is more valuable**. In that case, the bit-set is prefixed
>   by a tilde like this:
>
> ```
> sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, ~[], NULL) = 0
> ```
>
> Here the second argument represents the full set of all signals.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax ~[] is part of Javascript bitwise NOT empty array expression. C does not have any such operator.

Comment: open that github link and see the extension of file name.

Comment: @rsp - the file could be pre- or post-processed. Google using a web technology to perform the processing sounds plausible to me. Or maybe its like someone else commented, that it is some contraption invented by AOSP. That's my guess, at least.